# Discord.py Bot won't send command and i don't know why

Tags: discord, discord.py

It's a command that's supposed to send a server info embed and for some reason it's not replying with it but i'm getting no errors. This is my code,

```
@client.command()
async def serverinfo(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green())

    embed.set_author(name=f'{ctx.guild_name} Server Info')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)

    embed.add_field(name="Server Name: ", value=ctx.guild.name, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID: ", value=ctx.guild.id, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Members: ", value=ctx.guild.member_count, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner: ", value=ctx.guild.owner, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Region: ", value=ctx.guild.region, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Created: ", value=ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p GMT"))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I need some more information. For example, what is the client? Is your entire bot in one file? How are you attempting to run this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small typo in your code: `ctx.guild_name`. You used an '_' instead of a '.'
Thus you need to change: `ctx.guild_name` to `ctx.guild.name`.

If you changed that it will work:

```
@client.command()
async def serverinfo(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green())

    embed.set_author(name=f'{ctx.guild.name} Server Info')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)

    embed.add_field(name="Server Name: ", value=ctx.guild.name, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID: ", value=ctx.guild.id, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Members: ", value=ctx.guild.member_count, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner: ", value=ctx.guild.owner, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Region: ", value=ctx.guild.region, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Created: ", value=ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p GMT"))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```